# How to get a command to trigger with any keypress

Tags: python

```
import time, threading, os, sys, tty, termios
from colr import color

def slow_type_interrupt(phrase,speed,r_value,g_value,b_value):
    done = False # this acts as the kill switch, using if statements, you can make certain button presses stop the message printing and outright display it
    def type_out():
        for char in phrase:
            if done:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(color(char,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(speed)
        os.system('clear')
        print(color(phrase,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))

    t = threading.Thread(target=type_out)
    t.start()

    def getkey():
        ky = sys.stdin.fileno()
        Ab = termios.tcgetattr(ky)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            key = sys.stdin.read(1)

        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(ky, termios.TCSADRAIN, Ab)
        return key

    while not done:
        key_press = getkey()
        if key_press == 'a': 
            done = True
            os.system('clear')
            print(color(phrase,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))

slow_type_interrupt("Hello this is a test. Pressing 'a' will end this and immediatley display the message",.05,0,255,0)
```

I was making an answer for a question on here (The person was wondering how to make a "typing effect" where the letters are printed one after each other to give the effect that someone is typing the message out) I used a function to type out the message. Anyway, there is the "kill key" which stops the printing effect and just straight up prints the message instantly (in case the player wants to skip the effect). I was wondering if there was anyway to have it take any key as an input to skip the dialogue. For example, I want it to set done to True if any key is pressed.

Comment: does straigt up `if key_press:` work instead of `if key_press=='a':`

Comment: Yes it does work but it's a little weird about how it operates, for example, function keys don't work, and arrow keys cause some minor bugs. I was just looking for a solution that doesn't need to identify a key to trigger.

Comment: what does `getkey()` function return when pressing arrow buttons? It probably doesn't detect function keys, does it return anything when a function keys are clicked?

Comment: I found the solution, I just changed a few things and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help :)